# bootstrap Summernote reset/clear

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, wysiwyg, summernote

I would like to know how to reset or clear the bootstrap Summernote WYSIWYG editor using jQuery or JavaScript.

I tried below codes

```
$('#MyForm').delay(1000).resetForm(1000);
```

This dose reset the whole form except for the textarea with the Summernote

```
$('#SummernoteText').reset();
```

SummernoteText is the html textarea but the code doesn't do anything at all.

```
$('#SummernoteText').destroy();
```

Above seems to distroy the editor instead of clearing the editor.

Can someone point me out the way to do this.

Link to Summernote http://summernote.org/#/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#SummernoteText').code('');
```

Comment: In Summernote 0.8.1 use `$("#SummernoteText").summernote("reset");`

Comment: @Pawel Actually use $("#SummernoteText").summernote('code', '');

Using reset with disable other pieces of the summernote control like the slide to resize and the dropdowns

Answer (score 15):

A little late, but just to add:

---

**Option 1:**

```
$('#SummernoteText').summernote('reset');
```

*This solution will only work if your editor was initially empty*

This will reset your editor to its original state. Meaning, if you initialized it with any data, the same data will re-appear on reset.

---

**Option 2:**

```
$('#SummernoteText').summernote('code', '<p><br></p>');
```

The reason for adding the `<p><br></p>` tags instead of just plain `''` is that summernote editing area needs it for focus. [(Reference)](https://summernote.org/deep-dive/#isempty)

Comment: I understand usability of '<p><br></p>', however for me the @Raheel Hasan solution works even better (setting an empty string and making a focus afterwards) $input.summernote('code', ''); $input.summernote({focus: true})

Answer (score 5):

For Summernote 0.8.1 version use this simple code:

```
$("#SummernoteText").summernote("reset");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can build a custom button into the toolbar of the editor itself like this:

```
//first create the button
var clearAllButton = function (context)
{
    var ui = $.summernote.ui;

    // create button
    var button = ui.button({
        contents: '<b>x</b>',
        tooltip: 'Clear All',
        click: function()
        {
            $("#summernote_field").summernote('code', '');
            $("#summernote_field").summernote({focus: true});
        }
    });

    return button.render();
};

//now set the options to include it
$('#summernote_field').summernote({
    toolbar: [
    .
    .
    .
    .
    ['misc', ['clearAll']]
    ],

    buttons: {
        clearAll: clearAllButton
    },

});
```

Answer (score 1):

From there official docs :
just use this `$('#summernote').summernote('code', "");`

Comment: $('#summernote').summernote('code', "");
this is useful

Answer (score 0):

**This was tested with summernote 0.8.2.**

If you define your summernote element as

```
<textarea id="your-text-area-id" name="your-text-area-name" ></textarea>
<div class="summernote" id="summer-note-text-id"></div>
```

then you can blank text using

```
$("#summer-note-text-id").summernote("code", "");
```

@naribo 's answer is more detailed about the value to be set instead of just "".